# active menu in pages using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi i have this active menu which will gonna be active when clicking on the other pages in a wordpress site. I want that when i click on the other pages like for example in design menu when i click on the design page the design page will set it to `<div class="active"></div>` i already have a script and then added it to functions.php file i already got or set the active page in homepage, so the homepage now will set to active, but when i go to other pages, how will i ever get the other pages in a wordpress site? Here is my code below. I add a function in it.

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {

    if(is_home() && $item->title == 'Home' ){
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }elseif($item->title == 'search'){
                $classes[] = 'active';
        }elseif($item->title == 'design'){
             $classes[] = 'active';
        }

    return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

this code works in a homepage site. But when i go to other pages. How will i call the other pages in a wordpress?. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to check other page with this

```
if(is_page('your page name')){ 
    $classes[] = 'active';
}
```

hope this help

Comment: sorry for late reply, can you try to echo ID of the menu and use $item->ID instead of $item->title. And after you get those IDs, you can check them like this

    if ($item->ID == 22) {
        $classes[] = 'special-class';
    }

I tried and it work. Hope this help (again!)

Comment: Yes, I can, anything I can help you with?

Comment: Did you get any ID from echo $item->ID; ?

Comment: yes i tried to echo from homepage i get the ID but when i tried other pages cannot echo the ID no display this is what my code goes like

 if(is_home() && $item->title == 'Home' ){
        $classes[] = 'active';
    print_r($item->ID);
    }elseif(is_page() && $item->title == 'search'){
    $classes[] = 'active';
    print_r($item->ID);
  }

Comment: I think it was my fault in my explanation (i'm not good in English, sorry).
I meant I need you to change your function to function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
     echo $item->title . ' : ' . $item->ID . ' ';
     return $classes;
 }
and try to run this code to see the ID of each menu. Then you can use if ($item->ID == 'id that you got') { $classes[] = 'special-class'; }